# Maximum length of domain name

Tags: java, networking, guava

As I noticed class from google library `com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName` containts the following constant:

```
private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 253;
```

Code below, checks length during creation of InternetDomainName instance:

```
 checkArgument(name.length() <= MAX_LENGTH, "Domain name too long: '%s':", name);
```

But RFC-2181 says that:

```
A full domain name is limited to 255 octets (including the separators).
```

So, what is valid max length for domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straight from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System):

> The full domain name may not exceed the length of 253 characters in
>   its textual representation. In the internal binary representation of
>   the DNS the maximum length requires 255 octets of storage, since it
>   also stores the length of the name.

And this is from [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt):

> Each label is represented as a one octet length field followed by that
>   number of octets. Since every domain name ends with the null label of
>   the root, a domain name is terminated by a length byte of zero.

Comment: But a single byte suffices for the length, so we're still one byte off.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I've searched poorly.

Comment: @maaartinus, I found another reference and updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR

If you just want to use the domain *as a website*, the limit is: `255` characters.

If you just want to use the domain *with email*, the limit is: `253` characters.

### Source - As a Website

[**RFC2821**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) (April 2001) established the `255`-character limit on domains and [**RFC5321**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) (October 2008) retained this standard.  To quote both of them...

> 4.5.3.1.2. Domain
>
> The maximum total length of a domain name or number is 255 characters.

### Source - For Emails

An email address must be in the form of `a@example.com`, based on what we see from [**RFC821**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) (August 1982).  The `to` field in SMTP cannot exceed 255 characters.  The shortest possible local-part, `a`, is one character, `@` is one character, which leaves only `253` characters remaining for a domain.

Answer (score 0):

As per [RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) Section 2.1, *Host software MUST handle host names of up to 63 characters and SHOULD handle host names of up to 255 characters; which means it should be able to accept and process host names of any length up to 63 characters without issue, and should be able to accept and process host names of up to 255 characters if possible.*